# How to compare two frequency distribution (created using nltk FreqDist) in python3?

Tags: python, nltk

I am using nltk FreqDist to create frequency distribution using python3. I want to compare frequency distribution of whole corpus with frequency distribution of many text files one by one. In addition, I want to output some numerical values of the comparison.

corpusTokens = []

for document in documents_set:

```
    corpusTokens.extend(document)
    fdist = FreqDist(self.corpusTokens)
```

How to compare fdist of the whole corpus with fdist of some text file?